# Pandas Dataframe from a nested dictionary with list as values

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I'm newer to python and pandas and I can't figure out a way to push this dict into a dataframe

```
a_dict = {'position': [{'points': '57.95', 'name': 'Def'}, {'points': '121', 'name': 'PK'}, {'points': '383.1', 'name': 'RB'}, {'points': '299.96', 'name': 'QB'}, {'points': '177.8', 'name': 'TE'}, {'points': '616.42', 'name': 'WR'}], 'id': 'MIN'}
```

I have tried multiple FOR loops to iterate through the dict but the list keeps me from organizing it. The data is originally in a JSON format. Thank you!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Does this work for you : ``pd.json_normalize(a_dict, 'position',['id'])`` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the points and names as columns

```
points = []
name = []
for dct in a_dict['position']:
    points.append(dct['points'])
    name.append(dct['name'])
pd.DataFrame({'points':points,'name':name})
```

With the output

```
    points  name
0   57.95   Def
1   121     PK
2   383.1   RB
3   299.96  QB
4   177.8   TE
5   616.42  WR
```